# Windows Server 2012 Extremely Low Disk Space

Tags: windows-server-2012, disk-space-utilization

After running Windows update my server reports 20KB free. How can I free up space?

It is a Windows Server 2012 (not R2) instance on AWS. It happens to be a m1.small instance size.

Comment: Also, for whatever reason the disk clean-up tool I copied out of the WinSxS folder doesn't show the "Windows Update" temporary file removal options.

Comment: Did you run Windirstat?

Comment: You probably need to just buy more disk space.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think "buying more disk space" is an option on the table. I don't control the spending nor do I have access to the AWS control panel.

Comment: Size of your C: volume? Any application installed like SQL Server or Exchange or IIS? Use TreeSize Free to find folders tht are filling your disk

Comment: 30GB. The actual instance size on AWS is a m1.small. Very tiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally get enough disk space by deleting IIS logs, which allowed me to properly install cleanmgr.exe though the add roles and features dialog. After I restarted the server, I was able to free up close to 5GB in Windows patch files.